# Moving from mysql to MongoDB

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb

I am have spent years working in the LAMP stack, I am now moving to a MEVN stack and as a result need to get my around mongodb, particular how I would articulate 1:n and n:n relationships that I would traditionally user in MySQL.

A many to many would ordinarily have a pivot table in MySQL but my understanding is that mongodb, it's basically just one big document/object. So for example if I have a products table and a suppliers table in mysql and many suppliers can have many products, I would create a table like this,

```
CREATE TABLE products_suppliers (
     productID   INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
     supplierID  INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
                 -- Same data types as the parent tables
     PRIMARY KEY (productID, supplierID),
                 -- uniqueness
     FOREIGN KEY (productID)  REFERENCES products  (productID),
     FOREIGN KEY (supplierID) REFERENCES suppliers (supplierID)
   );
```

How would I represent this in mongodb? Would I just have a supplier of each product, or on each supplier a products array?

I am very confused, but I need to move to mongodb for future career development.

Comment: Keep in mind that MongoDB (and pretty much all noSQL databases) are really fast and useful **on very specific scenarios** (e.g. searching by PK). Relational databases, on the other hand, offer you a **world of flexibility and possibilities**, not yet possible in noSQL. Don't switch from one to another, but keep both and use them according to each problem you are facing each time.

Comment: [MongoDB Schema Design Best Practices](https://developer.mongodb.com/article/mongodb-schema-design-best-practices)